# HTAccess redirecting to www.www.www.www

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following htaccess file, which is setup to redirect /page1 to index.php?route=page1 etc. But if I attempt to go to my root ([www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com)) it is redirected to www.www.www.www.... I just can't work out what's gone wrong.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(\w+)/?$ index.php?route=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Thank you.

Comment: There's nothing in what you've posted that would do that. Does it matter whether you request HTTP or HTTPS? What are you seeing in the network traffic (in the browser dev tools)? What is the HTTP status code? To clarify, it is redirecting to `https://www.www.www.www.mydomain.com/` etc.?

Comment: It's redirecting to... http://www.www.www.www.www.www.www.www.www.www.www.www.www.www.www.www.www.www.mydomain.co.uk/www.www.www.www.www.www.... and so one

Comment: And looking at the dev window it's going to mydomain.co.uk, when www.mydomain.co.uk/www, then www.www.mydomain.co.uk/wwwwww etc

Comment: Unfortunately, there would seem to be "something else" in your application/config that is doing this. Nothing in what you've posted can result in this behaviour.